# И еще по поводу слова "по()ходу"

Tags: орфография, жаргон

Почитала обсуждение этого слова. И теперь хочу уточнить: получается, что, если оно употребляется в значении "по ходу дела", то пишется раздельно — "по ходу", а если в значении "похоже", то слитно. Так?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Устоявшейся грамматики у данного выражения нет, поэтому пишут его исходя только из собственных представлений. Те, кто воспринимает его одним словом, пишут слитно, те, кто двумя, - раздельно. Мне кажется,  что правильнее писать раздельно. Этимология от похоже представляется сомнительной, так как, во-первых, у "по ходу" значение шире, а во-вторых; в конце девяностых - начале двухтысячных выражение "по ходу дела" активно употреблялось с тем же значением, что и "по ходу", а про "похоже" и "походя" я такого сказать не могу.

Однако слово молодое, и в каком виде оно приживётся в языке (если вообще приживётся), пока сказать невозможно. Пишите так, как считаете нужным.

Answer (score 4):

Это сокращение от "по ходу дела", поэтому необходимо писать раздельно. Имхо.

Answer (score 2):

Слова "походу" на данный момент в русском языке не существует. "По ходу" используется в смысле "по ходу дела". А то, в качестве чего используется неологизм "походу", то есть "похоже на то, что", не закреплено в языке в качестве слова. Так что ответ на вопрос: только раздельно.

Comment: Другими словами: за категоричностью должны стоять аргументы.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, да. Как верно было сказано, нормативной базы под это слово в новом значении пока нет, но исходя из общих представлений о правописании наречий я склоняюсь к тому, что надо писать слитно. Как вы понимаете, дело не в том, что так пишет большинство в известных мне источниках, хотя и в том есть определенный аргумент, называемый "врожденная грамотность". Тут другое. Слово "ход" потеряло в этом "походу" свое исходное значение, а такие наречия обычно пишутся слитно.

Comment: Наречия далеко не всегда пишутся слитно.