# "Накрайняк" или "на крайняк" (слитно или раздельно)?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Как правильно писать:

- `накрайняк`
- `на крайняк`

?

Answer (score 5):

Похоже, раздельно, крайняк (мол. жаргон) - крайний случай. На что? на крайняк, падежный вопрос поставить можно, значит, это наречное выражение (сущ.+ предлог), наречием ещё не стало.

http://enc-dic.com/word/n/Na-kranjak-35821.html

Answer (score 3):

[По ходу](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/25186/%D0%98-%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83), нужно писать его раздельно.

Национальный корпус русского языка находит:

- [15 вхождений "на крайняк" (раздельно)](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%ED%E0%20%EA%F0%E0%E9%ED%FF%EA&p=0)
- [ни одного вхождения "накрайняк" (слитно)](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%ED%E0%EA%F0%E0%E9%ED%FF%EA)

Хотя устоявшегося правописания пока [нет](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=242080).